# Name for spigot mount

Tags: spigot

What is theme of the rectangular plastic plate?  I ask so that I can search for the item online an purchase more pieces.

The plate serves to brace the spigot and more importantly the pipe.

The successful/meaningful answer can be Googled to return a photo of a similar mount/plate.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that piece was brought/made for that use or just something handy that was DIY for that use?

Comment: There are some images for wall spigot spacers, but most are round, but do the same job.

Comment: I believe that it was bought for this purpose.  It would have been clear if it was not painted.

Comment: I've mostly seen spigots just directly fastened to the wall, though occasionally with an escutcheon plate or "oops plate" behind them to cover a sloppily drilled hole or because someone thought it decorative.

Comment: If that plate is plastic, it's about 30 years newer than the spigot.

Answer (score 2):

- Faucet mounting plate
- Hose bib* mounting plate
- Faucet mounting block
- Siding block

---

* Or "bibb", for some reason. It's the same word root as a child's table bib or a farmer's bib overalls. Blue-collar types like to spell things their own way. See also "electrical buss".

Answer (score 1):

Hose bibb mounting plate. They’re usually diamond or oval shape.